# request.vars.variablename gives empty string instead of None

Tags: python, web2py

I am using SQLFORM.factory to create a custom form. In this form I have a field as:
    Field('useraccount','unicode',default=None)

So as per my understanding, when user does not supply this value, request.vars.useraccount will be None. But it rather shows empty string value.
I can convert it to None by checking for empty string value but I do not want to do that.
Please suggest me any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the form is submitted, if the "useraccount" input field is empty, the browser still sends an empty string for that field, so that is what goes into `request.vars.useraccount`. Since an empty string is a valid value for a string field, web2py does not override that and convert it to `None` -- if you want it to be converted, you must do so explicitly. One option is to create a custom validator that converts empty strings to None.

```
def empty_to_none(value):
    return (None if value == '' else value, None)

SQLFORM.factory(Field('useraccount', 'unicode', requires=empty_to_none))
```

A validator must be a callable that takes a value and returns a tuple including a value (the original value or possibly a transformed version of it, as in this case) and either `None` (if there is no error) or an error message. The above validator is simple enough that it could easily be moved to a lambda:

```
SQLFORM.factory(Field('useraccount', 'unicode',
                      requires=lambda v: (None if v == '' else v, None)))
```

Also, note that setting the `default` value in `SQLFORM.factory` is only useful for pre-populating the form fields (and in this case, you are not pre-populating with anything). The only other use of the `default` attribute is for database inserts, but since this `Field` object is not part of a DAL table model, it won't be used for inserts anyway.

Comment: What value I should pass to empty_to_none function? It is showing error as "TypeError: empty_to_none() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)"

Comment: Solved!! I modified lambda function a bit. It is as given below : lambda v: (None if v == '' else v, None). Thanks a lot!