# Web2py SQLFORM.factory type and default attributes

Tags: python, web2py

I am using SQLFORM.factory to create a custom form as given below:

```
searchform=SQLFORM.factory(
    Field('useraccount','integer',default=None),
    Field('group','unicode',default=None), 
    submit_button = 'Search')
```

As per my understanding **useraccount** field should be of type **integer** and if user does not supply this value, I should get **request.vars.useraccount** as **None**. But it is accepting string values and if user does not supply this value I get empty string in **request.vars.useraccount**.

Please suggest me what do I do to achieve this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In forms, integer fields are simply string inputs with the CSS class set to "integer", so submitted values and therefore the values stored in `request.vars` are strings. When the form is processed, the string values are converted to integers for integer fields, so you should use `form.vars.useraccount` rather than `request.vars.useraccount`. You will find that `form.vars.useraccount` is `None` when the field is left blank and an integer when a value is submitted.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to use form.vars.useraccount and it returns integer value if supplied. But form.vars.group returns '' if not supplied. I think it should rather return None value.

Comment: No, because "group" is a string field, an empty string is a valid value, so it wouldn't be right for web2py to assume it should be `None` rather than empty (then there would be no way to enter an empty string if that's what you want). If you want to convert empty strings to `None`, you must do so explicitly (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18638236/440323).